# Drawing a custom chart in R - Displaying a time log of activites

Tags: r, visualization, rcharts

I am new to R, so I would like to know if its possible to create a chart like the figure below?

[image]

I would like to create a custom chart displaying the duration of activities completed by various people at a given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to propose another format for the data, where each activity has a start and an end time.

Load libraries. `dplyr` is only used for manipulating the dataset, and not strictly needed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

First we read the data set

```
activities <- read.csv2(
text=
    "Person; Activity; Activity start; Activity end
    A; Activity 1; 10:30; 11:30
    A; Activity 2; 12:00; 13:00
    A; Activity 3; 14:00; 16:00
    B; Activity 1; 10:30; 11:30
    B; Activity 2; 11:30; 13:00
    B; Activity 3; 14:00; 14:30"
) %>%
    mutate(
        Activity.start = as.POSIXct(Activity.start, format="%H:%M"),
        Activity.end = as.POSIXct(Activity.end, format="%H:%M"),
        Person = as.factor(Person)
)
```

So now we have the correct classes for the columns and we can plot this with

```
ggplot(activities) +
    geom_rect(
        aes(
            xmin=Activity.start,
            xmax=Activity.end,
            fill=Activity,
            ymin=as.numeric(Person)-.5,
            ymax=as.numeric(Person)+.5)
        ) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=levels(activities$Person), breaks=1:2) +
    geom_text(
        aes(x=(Activity.start + (Activity.end - Activity.start)/2), y=as.numeric(Person), label=Activity)
    ) +
    xlab(NULL) +
    ylab("Person")
```

which results in

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't normally the type of graph you'd create in R, surely you could pull it off with sufficient leg work.

I think this will get you jumpstarted:

```
require(lubridate)
require(ggplot2)

df              <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=14,ncol=3))
colnames(df)    <- c("Person", "Time", "Activity")
df$Person       <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A", "A", 
                     "B","B","B","B","B","B", "B")
df$Time         <- as.character(hours(c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16)))
df$Activity     <- c(NA, "Activity 1", NA, "Activity 2", NA, "Activity 3","Activity 3",
                     NA, "Activity 1", "Activity 2", NA, NA, "Activity 3", NA)  

ggplot(df, aes(Time, Person)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = Activity),
                                               colour = "white")  +   scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow (3))
```

[image]

You can take it to the next level by exploring the `ggplot2` options and doing further customization to get it closer to the picture you drew. For instance you should be able to

- change the dimensions of the bars
- overlay the labels from the legend (`geom_label` is one way)
- fine tune the tick marks

just by reading over and tweaking the options. I recently gave an answer on highly customized tick marks which you can find on SO with a quick search.